# symbol not found when import PySide QtGui in python and mac 10.9

Tags: python, pyside

My computer was damaged and forced me to buy a new Mac.  I was using MacOS 10.6 with python 2.7.2, PySide 1.0, and Qt 4.7 before.  I have setup the new machine by transferring everything from the old computer to the new one.  And things have started not working in python.

First, need to upgrade python to 2.7.6.  Otherwise, will have a segment fault error.  This error is fixed.

Then need to upgrade Qt to 4.8 and PySide to 1.2.1.  I install both by download the binary packages from the site.  Import QtCore has no problem.  And check that version are OK, both Qt and PySide.  However, got symbol not found problem when importing QtGui as indicated in the following.

```
>>> from PySide.QtGui import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN7QLayout11adoptLayoutEPS_
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so
```

Anyone has any idea?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Stupid I am.  Just find out that I install Qt 4.8.2 instead of the required version 4.8.5.  Problem fixed after reinstalled the correct version.

Sorry for all the trouble.